# Vue Router: Redirects don't work with history mode

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

For some reason, a regular redirect rule does't works with history mode, but works well with hash mode.

**Here is a code snippet:**

```js
let first = {
  name: "first",
  template: `<section><h1>First</h1></section>`
};


let second = {
  name: "second",
  template: `<section><h2>Second</h2></section>`
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router: new VueRouter(
    {
      mode: "history", 
      routes: [
        { path: "/",  redirect: { name: 'first' }}, // Works with hash mode, but does't with history
        { path: "/first",  component: first,  name: "first"},
        { path: "/second", component: second, name: "second" }
      ]
    }
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.1.3/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/first">First</router-link>
  <router-link to="/second">Second</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Why?

Comment: Have you configured your webserver correctly to support history mode? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: @TommyF No. Is it mandatory? In my case, page loads correctly, and router links work well, but nothing happens with redirects. Anyway, I tried to setup settings you linked, but it breaks everything for me, because my routed components placed in second segment of url like "your-domain.com/some-server-url/first" where "/some-server-url" served by server and CMS, but "/first" served by vue router

Comment: Check out `publicPath` (https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) and `base` (https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) options when deploying to a subfolder/route @yes-man .

Comment: @TommyF Oh, seems it what i wanted. Give me a little more time to check it out